# is there a way to dump single mysql table into a file using only php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have no access to the command line to use `mysqldump`. But I have full access to the tables and I can read all data from every table.
The problem is I need to save this data into a file on server but only way I can do it is by `file_put_contents` or similar php function and use some kind of standard mysql dump format to preserve table structure, that is full create string and data types, especially whether particular cell is empty string or NULL. I found this way: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

But using this query:

```
"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt' FROM $tbl_name"
```

Gives out this error:

```
Access denied for user '***'@'***' (using password: YES) [1045]
```

Ok but I can access all data in that table, so is it possible to iterate all rows and create output file using PHP functions that have in my case permission to write into server disk ?
But then do I must to reinvent the wheel and recreate *.sql dump format or is there a way to redirect output from sql command above to a variable in php and then create out file line-by-line ?

Comment: No direct way, but a pseudo-dump isn't that hard to do.

Comment: Have you seen [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/)? It's a single PHP file you upload, and then it acts like phpMyAdmin or other database front end. It can do some kinds of dumps - not sure if it can save to the server disk or not, but it's worth a look. Or someone might have a plugin for it to help.

Comment: That error means that the user does not have the FILE privilege. Who controls user privileges? Is this a hosted server or your own?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

Comment: @DavidSoussan: hosted, I got no access to db engine or shell only php.

Comment: First thing to do is to ask your host to grant the file privilege. I do wonder if this is a hosted server exaclty where you are going to save the file. In my experience they will not allow that. Are you saying that you want to save the file into the hosted web server file system? In mosr cases the db and the web will be on different servers.

Comment: @rsk82 - I added a script below for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I was able to create for a PHP "dump" script.

Now revised and tested.  This will export the following syntax:

- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
- CREATE TABLE
- ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY
- INSERT INTO TABLE

Here's the script:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "usr";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "my_db";
$table_name = ""; // If set, dumps only the specified table, otherwise dumps all
$file = "dump.sql";


$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Get a list of tables
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS `name` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$dbname}'";
if ($table_name) {
    $sql .= " AND TABLE_NAME = '{$table_name}'";
}
$db_result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$out = "";

// For each table
while ($table = $db_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Build the table
    $sql = "SHOW CREATE TABLE `{$dbname}`.`{$table['name']}`";
    $table_result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($create_table = $table_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Build the DROP TABLE DDL
        $out .= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$dbname}`.`{$table['name']}`;\n\n";

        // Build the CREATE TABLE DDL
        $out .= $create_table['Create Table'] . ";\n\n";

        // Build the FOREIGN KEY DDL for the table
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{$table['name']}' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '{$dbname}' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME != 'PRIMARY'";
        $fk_result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while ($fk = $fk_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($fk['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']) {
                $out .= "ALTER TABLE `{$dbname}`.`{$fk['TABLE_NAME']}` ADD CONSTRAINT `{$fk['CONSTRAINT_NAME']}` FOREIGN KEY (`{$fk['COLUMN_NAME']}`) REFERENCES `{$fk['REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME']}` (`{$fk['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']}`);\n";
            }
        }
        $fk_result->close();
        $out .= "\n";

        // Build the INSERT DML for the table
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$table['name']}`";
        $data_result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while ($row = $data_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $keys = array_keys($row);
            array_walk($keys, function(&$key) {
                $key = "`{$key}`";
            });
            $keys = implode(", ", $keys);
            $values = array_values($row);
            array_walk($values, function(&$val) {
                $val = "'{$val}'";
            });
            $values = implode(", ", $values);
            $out .= "INSERT INTO `{$dbname}`.`{$table['name']}` ({$keys}) VALUES ({$values});\n";
        }
        $data_result->close();
        $out .= "\n";
    }
    $table_result->close();

}

$db_result->close();
file_put_contents($file, $out);
```

Here's example output for a single-table dump in my DB I tested on:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_group`;

CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `user_group` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `user_group_type` (`id`);

INSERT INTO `user_group` (`id`, `type_id`, `name`, `created`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'Administrator', '2011-10-01 22:58:29');
INSERT INTO `user_group` (`id`, `type_id`, `name`, `created`) VALUES ('2', '1', 'Moderator', '2011-10-01 22:58:29');
INSERT INTO `user_group` (`id`, `type_id`, `name`, `created`) VALUES ('3', '1', 'Registered User', '2011-10-01 22:58:29');
```

Comment: Obviously, this won't be as robust as `mysqldump`, but it'll do the trick for most cases.

Comment: It might be better to use `file_put_contents( $file, $out, APPEND_FILE );` inside the loop at the end of each iteration (or buffer a few rows then write out) rather than outside if you are trying to dump a large table. Doing this outside the loop stores this in memory which may be limited causing larger dumps to fail with oom errors. Also, with large dumps, the real problem occurs when trying to re-import using php.

Comment: @SanuelJackson - Sure, that would be a good performance enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to get the structure and then a `SELECT * FROM` to get the data. From there you should be able to write the correct output to a file or the HTTP response.

Comment: Don't forget foreign keys.  This will require hitting INFORMATION_SCHEMA for those

Comment: And stored procedures, triggers, etc... Most people don't use any of those features though.

Comment: Title said single table so I kept it simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible the do the dump on the **remote machine**. So you can start **mysqldump** on the remote computer and directly store there the file. it then also not necessary to copy them.